# Actionscript: resizing bitmapdata with smoothing

Tags: image, actionscript, bitmap

```
var bd:BitmapData=new BitmapData(file.width,file.height);
bd.setPixels(new Rectangle(0,0,file.width,file.height),file.raw);

var scale_x_percents:Number = (w / bd.width);
var scale_y_percents:Number = (h / bd.height);
if(!stretch) {
    if(bd.width*scale_y_percents>=w) {
        scale_x_percents=scale_y_percents;
    }
    else if(bd.height*scale_x_percents>=h) {
        scale_y_percents=scale_x_percents;
    }
}
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(scale_x_percents,scale_y_percents);

var resizedBd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(Math.floor(bd.width*scale_x_percents), Math.floor(bd.height*scale_y_percents), true, 0x000000);
resizedBd.draw(bd, matrix, null, null, null, true); // true is smoothing option, it will blur sharpened pixels
```

Having problem with images resizing. Looks like smoothing is not working or something is missing in the code. Maybe Matrix should have something more?

Original image:

http://imageshack.us/a/img28/4784/dc7f2ec4b0f3323cdc4e01e.jpg

and it's result:

http://imageshack.us/a/img855/4784/dc7f2ec4b0f3323cdc4e01e.jpg

I can link a bunch of others images. Some strange pixel disposition exist.
Can it be fixed somehow?

I have tested jpeg quality 100% and stage.quality='best', but none of them give the required quality outcome.

Comment: Anyone? Any tip would do.

Comment: It's working fine for me, and your code seems ok... don't really know what to tell you (as this shouldn't be affected by platforms or any other scenarios or external configurations). Are you sure you are adding the correct BitmapData to stage?

Comment: BitmapData is picked from Loader object. From user machine.

Comment: Maybe the issue is in Math.floor? Some pixels are rounded into wrong side and from there i'm getting pixels distortion?

Comment: Not likely, as a lower width/height would just crop the image. I meant before that you should double-check if the BitmapData that you're adding to screen is actually "resizedBd" and not "bd" (with its Bitmap object's width and height changed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your problem is "nearest" sampling mode when drawing a BitmapData over a BitmapData. Perhaps the following might help:

```
var sh:Shape=new Shape();
sh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bd,matrix,false,true);
sh.graphics.lineStyle(0,0,0); // no lines border this shape
sh.graphics.drawRect(0,0,resizedBD.width,resizedBD.height);
sh.graphics.endFill();
resizedBD.draw(sh); // or with smoothing on
```

Using Flash's native graphics renderer will most likely perform at least a bilinear interpolation on a drawn bitmap, which seemingly is your desired result. Also, `stage.quality` applies if that shape is added to stage (BTW, you can use the shape to display an uploaded pic, then draw over a BitmapData in order to save.) But, this might not work - I can't test this right now.

Comment: It's working! Damn it. What magic is hidding behind this solution? :) Have to fill this void in my knowledge. :D

Comment: Here is new sample. You can compare it with the old one. http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/2591/ed4cfedff10d978a5b85e3c.jpg
 Thanks again! :)