# Scaling down a bitmap makes it look worse?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, flash-builder, image-scaling

I have this in AS3, meant to take a screenshot of your webcam and display a timestamp on it

```
var width = 196;
var height = 147;
var screenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width,height,false);
var overlay:BitmapData = new BitmapData(90,90,false);


var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
var m2:Matrix = new Matrix();
var scale:Number = 1;
m.scale(width/(myCam.width),height/(myCam.height)); //Scale for thumbnail.
m2.scale(scale,scale); //scale for timeRect
overlay.draw(timeGroup,m2);
screenshot.draw(VD1,m); //a 400x300 image
screenshot.merge(overlay,new Rectangle(0,0,timeRect.width*scale,timeRect.height*scale),new Point(width-(timeRect.width*scale)+1, height-(timeRect.height*scale)+1), 256, 256, 256, 256);
```

Because I'm intentionally scaling down a 400x300 image to be 196x147, it looks worse than it normally would, but passable.

However, if I adjust the `scale` variable, the `overlay`(timestamp) image that I'm merging with the screenshot looks really bad.

`overlay` when `scale` is set at 1,

[image]

`overlay` when `scale` is set at .5:

[image]

How can I keep the "quality" without losing all that detail?

Comment: Try putting those BMD in Bitmap Objects and enable smoothing on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrt, try to use `smoothing` paramater in `draw` method.

```
draw(source:IBitmapDrawable, matrix:Matrix = null, colorTransform:flash.geom:ColorTransform = null, blendMode:String = null, clipRect:Rectangle = null, smoothing:Boolean = false):void
```

Second, when you scale with low scale factor, you can try to scale in few steps (result will be smoother). Something like that (pseudocode):

```
            bigImageBD = scaleImage(sourceImageBitmapData, bigScaleFactor, BIG_IMAGE_WIDTH, BIG_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
            smallImageBD = scaleImage(bigImageBD, smallScaleFactor, SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
```

And last one, some magic from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406117/actionscript-resizing-bitmapdata-with-smoothing).